# Privacy violation in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, privacy, fortify

We are using the HPFortify demand to verify the security finding in my application. I got some privacy violation issues in my application but i didn't understand how to fix this.

```
 public void Info(LogMessage message)
        {
            SetContextProperties(message, LogLevelEnum.Info);
            log.Info(message);
        }

 private void SetContextProperties(LogMessage message, LogLevelEnum level)
        {
            if (message.Title == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Title");
            if (message.LogSource == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("LogSource");
            if (message.Message == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Message");

            ThreadContext.Properties["LogType"] = (int)level;
            ThreadContext.Properties["LogSource"] = message.LogSource ?? logSource;
            ThreadContext.Properties["UserName"] = message.UserName;
            ThreadContext.Properties["LogTitle"] = message.Title;
            ThreadContext.Properties["LogMessage"] = message.Message;
            ThreadContext.Properties["ServerName"] = message.ServerName;
            ThreadContext.Properties["IPAddress"] = message.IPAddress;
            ThreadContext.Properties["SessionId"] = message.SessionId;
        }
```

can anyone explain me what is the privacy violation in the above code and how to fix ?

Comment: Associating a `UserName` with an `IPAdress` maybe? Is there any fortify warning message to go with that security finding?

Comment: fortify is just displaying the line number and security issue message.

Comment: Would be revealing that line from your code open another security issue? Please help us to help you by including **all** available information.

Comment: Which line is the line number that it says is the problem.

Comment: is there any possible ways to secure my logmessage in c# ?

Comment: it says the line  log.Info(message); have the issue.